# Google scripts: Updating a column from a different tab only when numbers go up

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, vlookup

I'm attempting to create a database that will record the max price of an item in relation to an API for Black Desert Online. In the first column is the Index number of an item and the second column is the market price posted by this code into the [MaxPrice Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Trah.jpg) from the [API Prices Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ3la.jpg):

```
function readSalesNum() {
var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Prices");
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MaxPrice");

// Copy from 2nd row, 5th column, all rows for one column 
var index = sheetFrom.getRange(2, 2, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
var marketprice = sheetFrom.getRange(2, 5, sheetFrom.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

//Item name overwrites itself
sheetTo.getRange(1,1,index.length,1).setValues(index);
sheetTo.getRange(1,2,index.length,1).setValues(marketprice);
}
```

I need to keep track of the max price all items sell for. The API is updated every 30 mins. In BDO there are market caps for all items enforced by the Devs. Which is why originally the script would post a new column with updated prices every 2 hours, and then =MAX to find the current highest price of the item. However if a new item is added to the API (in aphabetical order) it skews all the data

I need a script that will look at column A in MaxPrices, find the matching number in Prices then post the current market price to column B in MaxPrices. Then will only update column B in MaxPrices if the current market price in the Prices tab goes up for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully the text of the commands are clear enough to just read and understand. I added `slice(1)` to the end of the `getValues()` to omit a header row.

```
  function myFunction() {
    var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MaxPrice");
    var data = sheetTo.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
    var maxPrices = Object.fromEntries(data.map(([id, price]) => [id, price]));
    
    var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Prices");
    data = sheetFrom.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
    
    data.forEach(row => {
      let id = row[1]; // column 2
      let price = row[4]; // column 5
      maxPrices[id] = maxPrices[id] === undefined ? price : Math.max( price, maxPrices[id])
    });
  
    var output = Object.entries(maxPrices).map(row => [...row]);
    sheetTo.getRange(2, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
  }
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much!! Can finally be done with this

Answer (score 0):

Ok so we need to create an existing list of max prices, compare/update them to the new prices, add new items.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Prices"); 
  var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MaxPrice");

  //three steps

  //1. create dictionary of MaxPrices from MaxPrice sheet
  var data = sheetTo.getDataRange().getValues();
  var maxPriceData = {}
  for (var i=1; i<data.length;i++){maxPriceData[data[0]]=data[1]}

  //2. Compare current prices from column E of the Prices to the dictionary
  data = sheetFrom.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i=1; i<data.length;i++)
  {
    var itemId = data[i][1];//B
    var basePrice = data[i][4];//E
    if (itemId in maxPriceData ){
      if (basePrice > maxPriceData[itemId]) maxPriceData[itemId] = basePrice;//updates dictionary if new price higher
    }else{
      maxPriceData[itemId]=basePrice;//adds new item to the item list
    }
  }

  //3. Update MaxPrice spreadsheet
  var output = [];
  for (key in maxPriceData){
    var itemId = key;
    var price = maxPriceData[key];
    output.push([itemId,price]);
  }
  
  sheetTo.getRange(2, 1,output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);

}
```

I haven't tested this against actual data so there might be a typo or two.

Comment: I gave your code a try, edited it to match up with the Data source page. However, it doesn't seem to keep the highest value in the MaxPrice tab if the prices changes in the Prices tab. I need it to always keep the highest price for each item even if the price were to go down in the Prices tab. [Data source page](https://imgur.com/a/rtlKj8u) Also this method won't work since the API keeps track of the total sold over 30 days which can oftentimes be a much higher number than the price.

Comment: Here's a video I made, which hopefully helps you to understand what I'm attempting to accomplish: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCZEpjbdsmA

Comment: Ah! ok much better to see the actual prices tab. Ultimately do you need to copy the new prices over as you currently have or just keep track of the maximum max price from column g that has ever been seen? Also it being a different MMO makes sense. I was wondering why you didn't just let TSM handle it for you!

Comment: Ultimately I need to just keep track of the maximum max price of each item in the Prices tab (column E) using its index number (column B). While making it so if a new item is added to the Prices tab automatically via the API, the data in the MaxPrice tab won't get skewed. Ex: new item is added and now all prices are off by one row, making all = VLOOKUP's after that new item inaccurate. https://imgur.com/a/F7IYzhf Haha yeah I get the feeling this would be much easier to make if it was for WoW XD

Comment: TBH I completely gave up on this O.o. I'll add what you wrote and start testing it. I truly can't thank you enough! Thank you Thank you Thank you!

Comment: Darn by the looks of it, it's still not keeping the higher price. It's correctly pulling the data from the Prices tab, however, it's still updating if the price goes down. Here's a link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-a8hSpPc6d9WY-JsIJPz_JrlKAWC-avfT4tUiKTN6i8/edit?usp=sharing added the line if (basePrice < maxPriceData[itemId]) maxPriceData[itemId] = maxPriceData[itemId]; is this correct?

Comment: try casting things into parseInt(), maybe it is comparing the strings

Comment: I apologize, how would I go about doing this? Would I be replacing var with parseint? like so:    parseInt (itemId = data[i][1]);//B